# Use Bitbucket Private Repository With Carthage That Ask For Passwords

Tags: git, bitbucket, carthage

I'm in the middle of setting up a framework I just created and then uploaded to a private repo on Bitbucket.

I've added the following to my Cartfile:

git "https://myUsername@bitbucket.org/myUsername/myFramework.git"

However when I run carthage update --platform iOS, I get the following error:

A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet https://myUsername@bitbucket.org/myUsername/myFramework.git /Users/jack/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/myFramework) failed with exit code 128:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myUsername@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled

How do you advise I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Switch to using ssh keys with the your account on Bitbucket.
Then use the carthage line:

```
git "git@bitbucket.org:<acct>/<repo>.git"
```